# find the number of duplicate values with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
 'datetime': ['24.06.2013 00:13:49',
  '24.06.2013 00:14:27',
  '24.06.2013 00:17:45',
  '24.06.2013 00:21:54',
  '24.06.2013 00:21:59',
  '24.06.2013 00:22:05',
  '24.06.2013 00:25:14',
  '24.06.2013 00:26:04'],
 'card_num': ['10', '10', '27', '10', '34', '10', '7', '3'],
 'type': ['cash_withdrawal',
  'cash_withdrawal',
  'refill',
  'cash_withdrawal',
  'payment',
  'cash_withdrawal',
  'payment',
  'cash_withdrawal'],
 'result': ['refusal',
  'refusal',
  'successful',
  'refusal',
  'successful',
  'successful',
  'successful',
  'successful'],
 'summ': [10000, 8000, 42431, 4000, 2347, 3500, 105, 999]})
```

It is required to find similar to fraudulent transactions, the criteria are as follows:

- card transactions within 20 minutes
- card transactions for withdrawal or payment
- card transactions > 3
- the first three or more card transactions with the 'refusal' status, the fourth or more card transactions with the 'successful' status
- each card transaction is less than the previous one

I have done the following:

```
df_report = df[(df.type != 'refill') & (df.result == 'successful')]
# left those lines where the type is not equal refusal and the result is successful
card = df_report.card_num
# get an array of these card numbers
suspicious = df[df.card_num.isin(card)]
# apply a filter to the main dataframe according 
# to the condition that the cards of the main df are contained in the filtered cards
```

Next, I need to remove those cards where operations on the card are <4, I don't know how to do this, can you tell me?
Further, this dataframe will need to be filtered by the result column, so that those cards remain with both successful and refusal.

Comment: Hi @Zaoza14, I'm struggling to understand your question. Please could you provide the resulting dataframe you are looking for? That will help.

Comment: to solve your 20 minute calculation, you can do the following `df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])` and `df['difference'] = df.datetime.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]')`  This will give you difference in seconds. Check for any that are < 1200

Comment: hi @muzzyq, resulting dataframe should be like this `df = pd.DataFrame(
{'id': ['1', '2', '4', '6'],
 'datetime': ['24.06.2013 00:13:49',
  '24.06.2013 00:14:27',
  '24.06.2013 00:21:54',
  '24.06.2013 00:22:05'],
 'card_num': ['10', '10', '10', '10'],
 'type': ['cash_withdrawal',
  'cash_withdrawal',
  'cash_withdrawal',
  'cash_withdrawal'],
 'result': ['refusal',
  'refusal',
  'refusal',
  'successful'],
 'summ': [10000, 8000, 4000, 3500]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding a sequential run of repeating categorical values you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Set up data
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'))
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

# Start filtering
df1 = df[df['type'] != 'refill']

# onehot encode 'type', then calculate the rolling rolling sum to find repeated sequences
df1 = pd.concat([df1, pd.get_dummies(df1['type'])], axis=1)
df1['withd>3'] = df1['cash_withdrawal'].rolling(4).sum()
df1['payt>3'] = df1['payment'].rolling(4).sum()

df1 output:
    id      datetime        card_num       type result      summ    cash_withdrawal payment withd>3 payt>3
0   1   2013-06-24 00:13:49 10  cash_withdrawal refusal    10000    1               0       NaN     NaN
1   2   2013-06-24 00:14:27 10  cash_withdrawal refusal     8000    1               0       NaN     NaN
2   3   2013-06-24 00:17:45 10  cash_withdrawal refusal     4000    1               0       NaN     NaN
3   4   2013-06-24 00:21:54 10  cash_withdrawal successful  3500    1               0       4.0     0.0
5   6   2013-06-24 00:42:05 34  payment         refusal   124125    0               1       3.0     1.0
6   7   2013-06-24 00:45:14 7   payment         successful   105    0               1       2.0     2.0
7   8   2013-06-24 00:49:04 3   cash_withdrawal successful   999    1               0       2.0     2.0

# filter for consecutive thresholds
df1 = df1[(df1['withd>3'] > 3) | (df1['payt>3'] > 3)]

df1 output:
    id  datetime            card_num       type     result  summ    cash_withdrawal payment withd>3 payt>3
3   4   2013-06-24 00:21:54 10  cash_withdrawal successful  3500    1               0       4.0      0.0
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to process the date frame if card transactions are mixed? corrected the dataframe in the question